# Trace spaces of Orlicz-Sobolev spaces.

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Recently I have the need of study trace spaces of Orlicz-Sobolev spaces. By looking in google I have discovered in this  [PDF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.cas.cz%2F~stebel%2Fseminar%2Fkrbec%2Ftalks%2FKalamajska.pdf&ei=quQdUvSXLMW9sQT1wYDwCA&usg=AFQjCNFIPp-ZnOhADrI-qYVBryqQros_NA&sig2=VmBqdRTI8bEZ3zttDfMlQQ) page 14 (not only in the PDF), that the main contributions come from the authors: A. Fougeres (1972), M-T. Lacroix (1974), G. Palmieri (1979). I tried to find the respective papers but with no result.

For example, the paper of Lacroix is: M.-TH. LACROIX, Espaces de traces des espaces de Sobolev-Orlicz, J. Math. Pures Appl. 53(9) (1974), 439–458.

So my question is: Does anyone know if I can find those papers on internet? Or, if there is some updated books or surveys which contains those results?

Thank you